# Is there a way to print assert expected and actual value in extent report

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, assertion, extentreports

I am currently working on selenium - nunit with c# and using extent report for reporting.
My requirement is : 
I want to log assert expected and actual value in report when assert is passed.
I know if assert fail , it fail saying expected and actual are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can build helper class method to do the assertion

```
public void AreEqual(object expected, object actual, string message)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, message);
    report.Log($"Expected {expected} Actual {actual}");
}
```

The report will happen only if the assertion passed. If you want the report always just move the report to the beginning of the method.